# Verifying IO bottleneck

Tags: virtual-machine, performance

We are working on a project to benchmark systems in virtual machines that share the same physical host.  I think we have a bottleneck with the system hosting the virtual machines, which may incorrectly seem like issues with the system we are testing.

In Linux, how can I verify that the IO throughput (in terms of disk, bus, or network) is saturated, to convince my team that the problem is with doing this virtualized instead of on different physical hosts?

Answer (score 0):

Tools like `iotop`, `iostat` (basic) or `sar` (advanced) may fullfill your needs.

Answer (score 0):

iperf is an excellent client-server tool for monitoring bandwidth (network) utilization across connections whether it be LAN or WAN.